# Dataannotation error messages

Tags: c#, resources, data-annotations

All of the DataAnnotation validation attributes can take a named parameter of     `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName` to specify an error message when vaildation fails:

```
        [Display(Name = "Stock Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        public DateTime StockDate { get; set; }
```

Is there any advantage to using these named parameters instead of referencing the resource directly?

```
        [Display(Name = "Stock Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.Required)]
        public DateTime StockDate { get; set; }
```

I haven't used resource files much before this project so there could be something I'm missing but referencing the resource directly seems a lot cleaner as well as catching typos with Intellisense.

Comment: does accessing the resource directly actually work? I'm pretty sure thats not posible.